# Audio Shiurim on Halacha Theory

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory

While there are plenty of websites that are offering audio recordings on "what the halacha is," i haven't found any that help teach you how you as an individual can learn about the halachic process to determine which opinions you should accept, and which you should ignore.

For example, there is a local community that follows the Shulchan Arukh....unless Ovadia Yosef disagrees with it, then they follow Ovadia Yosef, unless of course the Ben Ish Chai AND the the Radvaz disagree with Ovadia. And they believe that the Rambam's 13 principals of faith are binding, but absolutely nothing else that the Rambam said is binding in any way (they may not say that out loud, but it's certainly their practice).

In light of such contradictory practices, in which there seems to be little consistency and even less instruction on how these contradictory practices work, many find themselves not knowing how one should determine halacha, what things are more important, and which ones are less, or how to determine how much weight to give x authority over another. Is anyone aware of any shiurim that can equip someone with the tools to navigate the halachic world, rather than just being told what the halacha is?

Comment: Here are some programs that do this: [link](http://www.yu.edu/riets/semikha/) [link](http://www.smicha.co.il/)

Comment: @DoubleAA: ... plus _shimush_.

Comment: @msh210 The former of those, at least, has that as a requirement of the curriculum (like an MSW candidate does "field work" or a MD student does "rotations")

Answer (score 2):

A kollel member of Yeshiva University, Rabbi Jonathan Ziring, has an excellent series on [Methodology of Psak Halacha](http://www.yutorah.org/search/?s=ziring%20methodology%20psak), which discusses the factors that various poskim (mainly contemporary) take into consideration when arriving at a halakhic opinion. His shiurim in general are focused on the underlying methodologies of how Halacha is determined.

<sup>Disclosure: R. Ziring is a friend of mine</sup>